# Sync iPhone with multiple Macs

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization

Is it possible to sync an iPhone with multiple computers? I know the music will be restricted, and I don't mind. I want the contacts, bookmarks, etc. to be in sync across my home iMac and my MacBook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to synchronize contacts and bookmarks between several Mac and/or iPhone is to use MobileMe (now iCloud). It will sync all as you need where you want.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't have to buy MobileMe to sync contacts and calendar to multiple Macs and multiple iOS devices. This can be accomplished with only a free Google account. If you want more details on how to set it up, please ask.

As far as I know, there is no way to sync bookmarks without MobileMe.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just answered the question to how to keep your device's music library synchronized with 2 machines as well: [Sync iTunes U between 2 Macs via an iPod](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/sync-itunes-u-on-2-macs-with-an-ipod/2608#2608)

Answer (score 1):

One way to partly solve this (without paying for MobileMe) is by syncing certain data between different computers using [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/). (This approach was suggested in a [Super User question about syncing home folders](https://superuser.com/questions/40164/sharing-or-syncing-home-folders-between-macs) that I asked a year ago.)

To sync **contacts**, for example, share AddressBook's application data between your Macs like this:

1. Move the folder `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook` (on the computer where you have the data) to your Dropbox.
2. On each computer you wish to sync, create a symlink from `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook` to that folder in your Dropbox.

These screenshots show what the setup looks like on one of my computers:

[image]
[image]

(If you need more detailed instructions, please let me know!)

For **bookmarks**, you'd need to share some Safari application data (I don't know which files/folders exactly as I haven't done that myself).

Obviously this isn't optimal, but once you set it up, it works pretty well. I think Apple is sooner or later going to provide better (cloud-based, even wireless) sync across multiple devices (also to those who're not paying extra for the service). Well, at any rate they *should*, as they are lagging behind Google quite badly in this respect.

Comment: Oh, if you don't use Dropbox yet, feel free to use this [referral link](http://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTI4OTY2OTE5) when signing up — that way you get 2.25GB (instead of 2GB) to start with. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your music synced to one computer and contacts synced to another - no problem.

Comment: That's not really what was asked though -- it wouldn't keep contacts on the phone and two different computers all in sync.